# Read coordinates from geography SQL datatype to SqlDataReader in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sqldatareader, geography, reader

I've searched around and I've seen you can access the latitude with `myGeography.Lat` but it doesn't seem to work when trying to read to `sqldatareader`, this is what I'm trying:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myGeography.STDistance(geography::Point(somelatitude, somelongitude, 4326)) <somerange 

SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()

int lat,long    
lat = reader["myGeography.Lat"]    
long = reader["myGeography.Long"]
```

Answer (score 4):

SQL Geography is a data type that converts to Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.  Assuming myGeography is a geography, you can do it this way:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography geo = (Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography)reader.GetValue["myGeography"];
int long = geo.Long;
int lat = geo.Lat;
```

Comment: I get the error cannot aply indexing [] to a expression of type method group, if i remove getvalue it gives me a exeption